# Android Studio: automatically signing apps

Tags: android, android-studio, release

I'm uncertain about this part of the google docs for signing my app on android studios - http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html:

[image]

When I create my signed apps, in android studios, I usually go to: Build > Generate Signed APK and then fill in the details for my keystore. The release apk is then generated to a location I specify.

What does google mean in this section where I can sign my apps automatically? Do they mean I need to config android studio first before I click on assembleRelease in gradle?

[image]

Comment: change the `builtVarients` from debug to release then it will automatically make `.apk` built for release with release `keystore`

Comment: Where is the builtVarients?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you provide Signing info in Android Studio (alias, password, etc.) your release apk will be signed by specified key.

To choose release build variant you need to go View -> Tool Windows -> Build Variants and change 'debug' to 'release' and Run the app.

Comment: Thanks - I have tested your solution on Timber to see if it will log messages in debug / release mode and it works.

Comment: @MohamedAdelraZek, default logging will work, but Timber is used to customize its behaviour.